# Is there a way to wait for the completion status of a transfer?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am creating a S3 transfer to Big Query using Java and Google's Big Query Data Transfer package. My steps are:

1. Create a `TransferConfig` with my S3 details/permissions
2. Create a `DataTransferServiceClient`
3. Use steps 1 and 2 to create a `TransferConfigRequest` on Big Query
4. Create and start a `StartManualTransferRunsRequest` using the TransferConfig details
5. WAIT for transfer to be completed, then do additional things

I'm unsure how to approach step 5 and whether or not the Big Query Data Transfer package has a way to return a status once the transfer is completed. Does anyone know a recommended way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the public documentation that Google offers, you could create a cloud monitoring alert following these steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the **Monitoring** page.
2. In the navigation pane, select **Alerting > Create policy**.
3. Click **Add Condition** and select a condition type.
   4.Select metrics and filters. For metrics, the resource type is **BigQuery DTS Config**.
4. Click **Save Condition**.
5. Enter policy name, and then click **Save Policy**.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-monitoring#defining-alerts) you can see more details on how to correctly define cloud monitoring alerts.